# Changing chunk size in MongoDB gridfs using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gridfs

I am trying to use GridFs to store files more then 16MB, I would like to change to chunk size to 10MB.
Is there any way to achieve this with nodejs?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow...https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: why change it to 10MB?

Comment: Have you tried to set the `chunkSize` parameter in the file document ?